# Want to compile and build boost library with /md option on windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, boost

I have a requirement of building the boost boost_1_59_0 librabry with /md option instead of /mt.

could anybody here help me. I see there is one file build.jam where /mt is used at many places but not sure replacing /mt with /md in this file will fulfill my requirement.

Comment: I think (not sure) that building boost with `runtime-link=shared` will accomplish that.

Comment: I tried that but no luck :(

Comment: You could also try downloading the binaries from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.59.0/). You'll need to choose between 32 and 64 bits and also the correct version (msvc-14 is Visual Studio 2015; msvc-12 is Visual Studio 2013). Keep in mind that the file for Visual Studio 2015 32 bits expands to a little over 2.5 GB of space (I suspect the rest will be similar). Once you extract the files and set the include and lib directories, by using /MD in Visual Studio options autolink will find the appropriate libraries.

Comment: Could you write the b2 command that you use?

Answer (score 7):

```
/MT: b2 runtime-link=static
/MD: b2 runtime-link=shared  <= The default value
```

You can also build all libraries, as Grigoriy suggested. In this case, the output filenames will be different. For example:

```
/MT: libboost_regex-vc141-mt-s-1_65.lib
/MD: libboost_regex-vc141-mt-1_65.lib
```

Comment: Many many thanks for the detail explanation of the naming convention difference.

Answer (score 4):

You can run b2 with the option `--build-type=complete`. It should build [all supported variants of the libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)

OR

you can use something like this: `b2 variant=release,debug link=static` to build just the static version of the required library.